# Cannot import d3 voronoi map in svelte

Tags: d3.js, svelte, voronoi

I tried to make a voronoi map with [this](https://github.com/Kcnarf/d3-voronoi-map#installing) library by Kcnarf. But I don't know how to install it, I tried in svelte REPL but it shows this error:
`'default' is not exported by https://unpkg.com/d3-array@3.2.1/src/index.js, imported by https://unpkg.com/d3-weighted-voronoi@1.1.3/build/d3-weighted-voronoi.js`

I only write these imports:

```
<script>
    import * as d3 from 'd3'
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    import { voronoiMapSimulation } from 'd3-voronoi-map';
</script>
```

In the github, it's written `In vanilla, you must load the d3-weighted-voronoi plugin prior to this one, and a d3 global is exported:`. It's not vanilla, but I give it a try to add:

```
<svelte:head>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/Kcnarf/d3-weighted-voronoi/v1.1.3/build/d3-weighted-voronoi.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/Kcnarf/d3-voronoi-map/v2.1.1/d3-voronoi-map.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
```

I read somewhere that I have to add `on:load` inside the scripts, but I don't know how the function should work inside it. If I just write the code like `const simulation = voronoiSimulationMap(data)` without any imports (but with `<svelte:head>` scripts), it shows `undefined is not a function` because the function's not declared.